# DRF Invalid pk object does not exist for foreign key on POST create

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two classes related to each other.
One class I have made the primary key a char field so I can easily reference to it or create it to match the id of the actual object (all objects will have this unique name).

```
from django.db import models

class Ven(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=80, primary_key=True)
    statusOn = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Device(models.Model):
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ven_id = models.ForeignKey(VEN, related_name='devices', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['id', 'device_id', 'ven_id']


class VENSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VEN
        fields = ['id', 'statusOn', 'devices']


class DeviceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    logger.info("DeviceList: view")

    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
```

however when I try to run my test:

```
class DevicesTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = Client()

    def test_create_device(self):
        device = {
            "ven_id": "TEST_VEN_1",
            "device_id": "TEST_DEVICE_1",
            "statusOn": True,
        }
        response = self.factory.post('/devices/', data=device)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

my response returns 400 and states:

`b'{"ven_id":["Invalid pk \\"TEST_VEN_1\\" - object does not exist."]}'`

I'm trying to write a custom `create` in my serializer to create the ven if it does not exist but it's not being called. Data is being validated else where. My breakpoint in my view set's `perform_create` also does not fire.

I don't want to write a bunch of workaround code for something that should be straightforward. I know I'm missing/messing something up somewhere.

Comment: You will have to define your own `ven_id` field in the serializer. So something like `ven_id = serializers.CharField()`, then handle the validation manually yourself

Comment: so I tried that and get `Cannot assign "'TEST_VEN_1'": "Device.ven_id" must be a "VEN" instance.` 
Do you mean handle the validation in the ModelViewSet before this is thrown?

Comment: yeah still was a no go, currently trying VENSerializer(read_only=False) but I think that means the payload changes to accept an object instead of a char field.

Comment: The error about `must be a "VEN" instance.` could mean the default `create` implementation in the serializer was used. Can you share your custom `create` in your serializer?  If you haven't done so, will have to implement your own `create`, where you handle creating the `Ven` if it doesn't exist, or use an existing one (e.g. using `get_or_create`)

Comment: already have have created implmented with a breakpoint (last thing I mentioned in my question). This happens above this probably in my perform_create` but this is a lot of work for essentially just wanting a character to be returned in lieu of an entire object -- whereas I can take care of object creation using the string and etc on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to customize the `create` method in the `DeviceSerializer`.

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ven_id = serializers.CharField()
    status_on = serializers.BooleanField(write_only = True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['id', 'device_id', 'ven_id']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ven_id = validated_data.pop('ven_id')
        status_on = validated_data.pop('status_on')
        try:
            ven = Ven.objects.get(id = ven_id)
        except Ven.DoesNotExist:
            ven = Ven.objects.create(id = ven_id, statusOn = status_on)

        new_device = Device.objects.create(ven_id = ven, **validated_data)
        return new_device
```

Comment: nope. fails some sort of validation before even this.